# Infering generics not at instantation, but later / updating a generic's type

Tags: typescript

Given the example below, can one get the typescript compiler to understand that `baz`'s return type, must be `string` as it can be inferred from `foo.a('aString')` that it's a `string`?

```js
const fn = <T,S>()=>{
  let s: S
  let t: T
  return {
    a: <Z extends T=T>(arg: Z)=>{
      t = arg
      return s
    },
    b: <V extends S=S>(arg:V)=>{
      s = arg
      return t
    }
  }
}
const foo = fn()
const bar = foo.a('aString')
// currently,baz's type is 'unknown', but it is determinable that the type should be 'string'
const baz = foo.b('aString')
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=9&pln=5&pc=21#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmGBeGAeAKgGgMoD4AUAlErgN4BQMMANgKawQBcM2lN9MUz6bATvQFdeiClSoBDZqgBaMWgA8otMABMIMdEnQFxvAObNpxMmzGdkMXXtNj+UIYgg2AvphsAjKQDU5i5WpYkPHwrRi9jUTMYdRQrGyo7B04XNmdyNNBIWDgQEABGCwRUaF4ASzA9TGioMoqCQnJM6HhcwrAiRvBm911C3IA6cXwAcnFsGvK9YYaAehmYYHFEcFoYPQ4oAAtVqABPAAdaCGAy-dhQAFt90rpeThAYAVVaXmgllU5N8VgegC9h9SJYScA60NxzGAXATdVYAiYVYYwHoQWgfcCfVYQAT7fbUUqomDlHK8C7fUrgAD8nSySPEvz6IH67hGY3hU0IMCAA)

A solution is to define `const foo = fn<string, string>()`.  However, this requires one to specify both types upfront when `foo.a('aString')` may be the best place to infer `T`, rather than having to explicitly specify the type.

I suspect not ... but one can have hopium!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround solution:

```js
const fn = <T,S>(t?: T, s?: S)=>{
  return {
    a<NewT>(arg: NewT) {
      return fn<NewT,S>(arg,s)
    },
    b<NewS>(arg: NewS) {
      return fn<T,NewS>(t,arg)
    },
    t(){
      return t as T // removed undefined for simplicity
    },
    s(){
      return s as S // removed undefined for simplicity
    }
  }
}
const foo = fn()
const bar = foo.a('aString')
const t = bar.t() // string
const s = bar.s() // unknown
const baz = foo.b('aString') 
const t1 = baz.t() // unknown
const s1 = baz.s() // string
const foobar = bar.b('aString') 
const t2 = foobar.t() // string
const s2 = foobar.s() // string
```

Answer (score 1):

`fn` functions emulates `class`. TS has good support for classes, hence I think it worth using `class` in your example.
See this approach:

```js
class fn<T, S>{
  s: S | undefined = undefined
  t: T | undefined = undefined

  constructor() { }

  a<Z extends T = T>(arg: Z): asserts this is this & { t: Z } {
    this.t = arg

  }
  b<V extends S = S>(arg: V): asserts this is this & { s: V } {
    this.s = arg
  }

}
const foo: fn<string, string> = new fn<string, string>()

foo.a('aString')
foo.t // 'aString'

foo.b('bString')
foo.s // 'bString'
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Na2oPm)

If you mutate `this` in your class and you want to track this mutation, you need to use [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

However, it does not work in your example because you call `fn` without explicit generic arguments. If TS is unable to infer toy of generic it uses `unknown` as a default type.

See this function:

```js
const bar = <T,>() => {
  return 42 as any as T
}
//const bar: <unknown>() => unknown
bar()
```

`T` can't be infered, because it was not provided. Same case is with `fn` function

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It's similar to the one that I said was not ideal: const foo = fn<string, string>() I don't want to specify the generics but rather have them inferred when the methods are called. Change to const foo = new fn() in your code to see what I mean.

Comment: @TrevTheDev so, in order to infer these types you should provide arguments to `fn`. TS infers from left to right.

Comment: my question was how one can not provide the types at instantiation, but rather have them inferred when the methods that provide them are called.  Before that, they should be treated as `unknown` afterward as the type inferred in the method.

Comment: @TrevTheDev typescript generics are immutable

Comment: yup, that's my understanding, but I was hoping that typescript provided some mechanism to change type after a method is called or property is set.  That's required to enable the modeling of the state of an object.  The closest solution I've seen so far is probably the `asserts` you recommended, however that is not really a solution at all as it only supports narrowing and not reassignment.

Comment: @TrevTheDev I think you are looking for `typestate` pattern or `builder` pattern. SOmething like [this](http://cliffle.com/blog/rust-typestate/) or [this](https://catchts.com/type-state)

Comment: Yup, type state is exactly what I'm trying to do - thank you for the links and name! Typescript seems to not implement that pattern well.  I'm trying to chain functions - similar to the new pipe operator `|>` except with more flexibility. Prior function calls limit the state of subsequent functions.  I.e. a string output from one function, means that string is an input in the next function.  One can define types upfront - but this leads to a lot of duplication - and it's exponential - the longer the chain, the more duplication - as all downstream types need to be defined upfront.

Comment: Maybe worth trying function composition?

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm doing - except I'm making them `async` -so all results are passed back via callback.  In function composition, the types are built up as one adds new functions and I haven't found a good way to model that in typescript.

Comment: You can check my article https://catchts.com/FP-style#compose and linked answers on the bottom

Comment: that's a great article - thank you for sharing - you have a deep understanding of typescript and functional programming.  I created [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgZPyW) simplified version of what I'm doing, and was hoping you would please be so kind as to add typing to it?  Especially the inferring of types based on input provided.

Comment: @TrevTheDev thank you for kind words. TS does not like mutating. Try to avoid using `let` and then mutating it. Also, could you please provide at least some types, TS swearing about each line

Comment: I've [updated](https://tsplay.dev/w8E3dN) the code to include much of the typing - the typing is still broken as I don't know how to solve the problem.  Re `let` I'd gladly take on board any suggestions you have as to how to improve this code.

Comment: thanks for your input! It helped me to find [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/NV4QBW) which now works!